# Streaming Analytics job is only able to use up to 6 Streaming Units

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I am load testing my Azure IoT Suite solution.  I am currently testing with 3,000 messages / second.  My Azure Stream Analytics job pulls data from IoT Hub and stores it into a partitioned DocumentDB database.  I have calculated that I will require 12 Streaming units. When I start the job I get the following error:

> Streaming Analytics job '' is only able to use up to 6
>   Streaming Units based on the provided query.  Please adjust the number
>   of Streaming Units or update your query and restart the job

What do I update in my query to get past the 6 Streaming Units limit?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add PARTITION BY clause to be able to use more than 6 SUs. Please take a look at this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-scale-jobs/